# How can I skip the specific methods from brakeman scanning process + Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, security, brakeman

I am using the `brakeman` for security check in my app. I want to skips some methods those are 
[false positive](http://brakemanscanner.org/docs/reducing_false_positives/) and I `Mark Methods as Safe`, but I want to add a `flag` to method to skip that method while `brakeman` scanning the application.

Example:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  # I want to skip this method when brakeman scan the application
  # Kind of `flag` to skip the method
  def profile
    # ..
  end

  def company
    #..
  end
end
```

**I want to add a file where I can manage that which tag need to be skip.**

Do any one know how can I do that?
Your help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

No, there is no way to skip processing a particular method.

You can ignore specific warnings via an [ignore file](http://brakemanscanner.org/docs/ignoring_false_positives/). The file can be created/managed by running Brakeman with `-I`:

```
brakeman -I
```

Comment: But there is a way to reduce the warnings http://brakemanscanner.org/docs/reducing_false_positives/, but not sure how to implement?

Answer (score 0):

As @justin mentioned

```
brakeman -I
```

works for me, it will ask few options to either override or add new warning into

```
config/brakeman.ignore
```